# Automatically add a tag according to custom metadata

Tags: metabox, tags

I'm trying to figure out how to make a function to automatically add a "featured" tag to a post, based on a checkbox in a metabox I've added to the edit screen.

I think the function I need to use is [wp_set_object_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms), but I don't get how it works. I know how to check if those checkboxes are active or not, but that´s all.

I hope someone can put me on the right track with this.

Answer (score 2):

I accidentally found this question searching for something similar, and I liked your approach, so I improved your code a bit.

1. I updated the action hook so it's being triggered on save AND update.
2. Added the `wp_remove_object_terms` to be able to switch back ( toggle ) custom meta box value ( in this case check-box value ).

function works fine with both, regular and custom post types, also can be used with tags, categories or custom taxonomies too.

```
function set_term( $post_id, $your_term ){

    $post_id = get_the_ID();

    $your_term = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'your_custom_meta_id', true ); 

    // check the custom meta-box checkbox value
    if ( $your_term == '1' ) {
        // Create a new term if checked
        wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'YourTerm', 'your_custom_taxonomy', true );
    } else {
        // Remove the created term if unchecked
        wp_remove_object_terms( $post_id, 'YourTerm', 'your_custom_taxonomy' );
    }
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'set_term', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found the problem.

This code works like a charm:

```
function is_featured_post(){
$postid = get_the_ID();
$featured = get_post_meta($postid, 'wpcf-slider-if', true); if ( $featured == 1 ) { 
    wp_set_object_terms( $postid, 'Destacado', 'post_tag', true );
}
}

add_action ( 'publish_post', 'is_featured_post' );
```

But it only works in standard post, not in custom post types. There is a hook to do the same with custom post types?

Comment: Yes there is see this article http://www.wphub.com/custom-post-type-publish-action-hook/

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into the action with `add_action ( 'publish_post', 'your_function' );`

Write a function to check if the checkbox is checked and if so update the posts term

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API

Comment: I do this:

`function is_featured_post(){
 $postid = get_the_ID();
    $featured = get_post_meta($postid, 'wpcf-slider-if', true); if ( $featured == 1 ) { 
     wp_set_object_terms( $postid, 'Destacado', 'post_tag', true );
 }
}
add_action ( 'publish_post', 'is_featured_post' );`

But it doesn´t work. To me, the code looks fine. I don´t know what I´m doing wrong.